# Getting Null pointer exception while testing class Edit text field in android

Tags: java, android

This is the class of which I want to test EditText. But when I try to assign that EditText field in the Test clas it shows an null pointer exception.  I have omitted other use less code for the problem

```
public class LogInActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button signUpButton;
    private Button logInButton;
    private Intent signUpChoiceIntent;
    private Intent homeActivityIntent;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private EditText usernameTextField;
    private EditText passwordTextField;
    private HumLogController humLogController;
    private String error;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        humLogController = (HumLogController) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("controllerObject");
        setIntentAndButton();
    }
   private void setAndCheckFields(){
         /** I want to test this, (view with id:- logInUsernameField ) which is working fine in practice, but not passing the test. When I try to call the same id in Test class with instance of this class, it gives a null pointer exception. */
        usernameTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logInUsernameField);

    }
```

This is the test class where I am testing for the EditText field, but giving a null pointer exception

```
public class LogInActivityInstrumentTest extends InstrumentationTestCase{

    LogInActivity logInActivity;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        super.setUp();
        logInActivity = new LogInActivity();
    }

    public void testUsernameTextViewNullTest(){
// The line below is line 23. Which is giving null pointer Exception...? 

        EditText text = (EditText) logInActivity.findViewById(R.id.logInUsernameField);
        assertNotNull(text);
    }


    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception{
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

The log cat is given below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
at com.example.praduman.humlog.tests.LogInActivityInstrumentTest.testUsernameTextViewNullTest(LogInActivityInstrumentTest.java:23)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Comment: `logInActivity = new LogInActivity()` : don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an Activity simply calling its constructor as you did. In a test context, you need some kind of instrumentation to allow everything to work properly. Try to take a look at [Espresso](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) (for in device tests) or even [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) (for JVM tests).

Answer (score 0):

You can not create an instance of your activity using the constructor like ou have done in the above code.

Try changing the following in your `LogInActivityInstrumentTest`

```
public class LogInActivityInstrumentTest extends InstrumentationTestCase<LogInActivity>{

    public LogInActivityInstrumentTest() {
        super(LogInActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        super.setUp();

        logInActivity = new getActivity();
    }
}
```

The documentation for running tests can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html), on developer.android.com.

In the code you have posted - simple creating the Activty using its constructor does not run it through the lifecycle that an activity expects. The reason for your `NullPointerException` is the fact that `onCreate` has not been run, meaning that you are trying to look up a view before you have called `setContentView()`, therefore, the view really is null.